# Minecraft Pocket Edition ModPe Categorys

Tags: javascript, minecraft

I'm fairly new to modding (not new to coding btw) and I'm wondering what is the correct way to reference a creative inventory category.

This is what I have:

`Item.setCategory(1002, ItemCategory.ToolsandWeapons);`

`Item.setCategory(1001, ItemCategory.DecorationBlocks);`

for the ''ItemCategory.ToolsandWeapons" & "ItemCategory.DecorationBlocks" have I referenced ToolsandWeapons and DecorationBlocks correctly?? If not can I have some help? Thx :D

Answer (score 0):

`ItemCategory.DECORATION;`
`ItemCategory.FOOD;`
`ItemCategory.INTERNAL;`
`ItemCategory.MATERIAL;`
`ItemCategory.TOOL;`

This are all Category, which u can use in MCPE.

The last one you will need for Tools and weapons :D
and the first one for Decoration.

For more information about ModPE (for example all Entity Type, functions, etc) you can go to the Settings of Blocklauncher in Nerdy Stuff in Dump ModPEScripts, or click on this link here:

https://github.com/peacestorm/ModPE-scripts/wiki/ModPE-Script-Dump

I hope I could answer your question this time.